# datepicker в компоненте Angular

Tags: angular, datepicker

Использую ng6 и библиотечку https://sherweb.github.io/ngx-materialize/home#demo-application, при динамическом создании компонентов DatePicker не растягивается на страницу а  остается в компоненте. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При чем TimePicker работает хорошо и растягивается на всю страницу. Подскажите в какую сторону копать, timePicker и DatePicker находятся в DOM на идентичных местах.

Answer (score 0):

Сам сказал сам посмеялся, долго на самом деле мучался над этим вопросом. В итоге все просто в materializecss, в options есть поле container: 'body', по умолчанию он опредялся компонентом, при явном указании body все работает хорошо.